# Using css2pdf to generate pdf documents from html

Tags: angularjs, jspdf

This is a followup post from another stackoverflow question that this site would not let me paste (Apologies for not extending that other post)

Based on Kevin Brown's suggestion, I experimented a bit with css2pdf and I ran into a few issues - here is the modified plunkr

http://plnkr.co/edit/xBO4DjcOlrmH82bAqyR1?p=preview

```
app.service('PdfGenService', function(){
this.generatePdf = function(jQueryElement) {
     jQueryElement.show();
     function generate(){
       xepOnline.Formatter.Format("toGenerate",{render:'download'});
     }
     setTimeout(generate, 1000);

};
});
```

@Kevin (If you see this post),

My questions are as follows

1. What am I doing wrong with - The downloaded pdf does not have any of my charts (it has other content correctly rendered)
2. I cannot click on the contact for cloudformatter.com for me to ask them how to get a commercial use license since we cannot go outside our domain for security reasons. How do I reach out to them? Could you give me some more pointers on RenderX or any other engine that does similar things?

Thank you

Comment: Did you ever make any progress on this? I'm considering doing something that I think is VERY similar (trying to export multiple highcharts elements to pdf)